# Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $C\subset B,D\subset B$. Prove that $f^{-1}(C\backslash D)=f^{-1}(C)\backslash f^{-1}(D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

hello everyone I have question

> **Q**
>   Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $C\subset B,D\subset B$. Prove that $f^{-1}(C\backslash D)=f^{-1}(C)\backslash f^{-1}(D)$?

Notice,

(the inverse image not inverse function)

I hope some one can prove 
thank you

Comment: Here $f^{-1}$ doesn't denote the inverse of $f$ (which may not even exist), but rather $f^{-1}(Y)=\{a\in A: f(a)\in Y\}$, for any $Y\subseteq B$.

Comment: See also: [Proof of $f^{-1}(B_{1}\setminus B_{2}) = f^{-1}(B_{1})\setminus f^{-1}(B_{2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1372833)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove equality of two sets show that each is contained in the other.  So for one direction assume $x \in f^{-1}(C \setminus D)$.  This means $f(x) \in C \setminus D$, so $f(x) \in C$ but $f(x) \notin D$.  Thus $x \in f^{-1}(C)$ but $x \notin f^{-1}(D)$, giving $x \in f^{-1}(C) \setminus f^{-1}(D)$.

That proves $f^{-1}(C \setminus D) \subseteq f^{-1}(C) \setminus f^{-1}(D)$.  Now I leave it to you to emulate what I've done and prove the other direction.  Once you have both directions you will have shown that $f^{-1}(C \setminus D) = f^{-1}(C) \setminus f^{-1}(D)$.

Answer (score 3):

$x \in f^{-1}(C\backslash D) \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in C\backslash D \Leftrightarrow f(x)$ is in $C$ and not in $D \Leftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}(C)$ and $ x \notin f^{-1}(D) \Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(C)\backslash f^{-1}(D)$

Comment: thank you very much it is clear