# Prove that $f^{-1}(Y-V) = f^{-1}(Y)-f^{-1}(V)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f:X\rightarrow Y$.
Set $B = Y - V$.
Then, why is $f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(Y)-f^{-1}(V)$?

This statement is given in **Topology** (2e) by **Munkres**.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the topologies on $X$ and $Y$: If $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $f \colon X \to Y$ is a function, then $f^{-1}(Y \setminus A) = X \setminus f^{-1}(A)$ for every subset $A \subseteq Y$.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372833/proof-of-f-1b-1-setminus-b-2-f-1b-1-setminus-f-1b-2). You can find some related results [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in f^{-1}(B)$ i.e $f(x)\in Y-V$ i.e $f(x)\in Y$, $f(x)$ not $ V$ i.e $x\in f^{-1}(Y), x$ not in $f^{-1}(V)$ i.e $x\in f^{-1}(Y)-f^{-1}(V)$.